# Trying to Incorporate Multiple README.md Files Into A Doxygen Dump

Tags: markdown, documentation, doxygen, readme

I don't see an answer for this above, so here's my question:

I have a set of projects. They are expressed as nested Git Submodules, like so:

```
MAIN-PROJECT
    LIBRARY-1
        LIBRARY-2
            ETC.
```

Each submodule has a README.md file and CHANGELOG.md file (standard GitHub model):

```
MAIN-PROJECT
    README.md
    CHANGELOG.md
    LIBRARY-1
        README.md
        CHANGELOG.md
        LIBRARY-2
            README.md
            CHANGELOG.md
            ETC.
```

What I want to do, is use the "Root" README as the mainpage in the dump, but still render the internal READMEs, as each has good information.

I don't want to individually build each Doxygen dump. I want to have a single, monolithic dump that starts in the "Root." This is because I want the classes and whatnot to link.

Is there a way to do this? I tried specifying the "Root" README explicitly, but it looks like you can only give the filename, not the path. This means that EVERY README is considered for the post, and the one that wins is the "deepest" one.

Comment: Did you place a `\page` command in the lower level README files ? Did you try to specify the README with a ful path (./README.md) ?

Comment: Thanks. I did try the full path, and that didn't work (It looks like it wants only the file name, and looks through what you included). Let me look at the \page commands.

Comment: I wrote full path but I meant relative path (sen the ./README.md). Probably also a m ix of the path and the use of the \page command. Wich version of doxygen are you using (might be essential)

Comment: I'm using the latest (which is a bit old) 1.8.14, on a Mac. I could have borked the pathname. I'm revisiting everything right now. I dismissed the \page command, and I have a feeling I may be able to combine that with \mainpage to give me what I need. If it does, I might suggest that you phrase it as an answer, so I can give you a nice greencheck.

Comment: OK. I *ALMOST* have it. The \page thing was whut done it, and I am happy to give you a nice green check, if you rephrase your comment as an answer. The issue I have now, is that the internal README files are bing displayed in the list as both README (which shows nothing), and the page by title (which shows rendered markdown). I'm sure that I'll figure that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use multiple 'README.md' file there are a few things to take in consideration:

- specify the major README.md with a relative path when using `USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE`.
- alternatively use `\mainpage` in the master 'README.md'
- use `\page` in the other 'README.md' so one can  distinguish the different files.

Note also the possibilities of `\subpage` and `\ref` to refer to other pages